# jQuery CSS change table color when value changes

Tags: php, jquery, css

I want every time my value is  below 10,  my table row's background color changes  into red.

And every time my value is >=10 then row's background color changes into green.

This should happen for all of my rows.

jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = $("#value10").val();
    var valueNum = parseInt(value);
        if  (valueNum < 10){
            $("#row").css({
            backgroundColor: 'red'
        });
        }else{
            $("#row10").css({
            backgroundColor: 'green'
        });
        }    
});
```

PHP Code - Table

```
<table>  
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Περιγραφή</th>
            <th>Kατασκευαστής</th>
            <th>Σειρά</th>
            <th>Χρώμα</th>
            <th>Μήκος</th>
            <th>Ποσότητα</th>
            <th>Τοποθεσία</th>    
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>

                <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stock_alumil;";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);      
                    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                        while  ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>
        <tr id="row10"> 
            <td style="font-weight: bold"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
            <td style="font-style: italic;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td style="font-style: oblique;"><?php echo $row['buyer']; ?></td>
            <td style="font-style: italic;"><?php echo $row['seira']; ?></td>          
            <td><?php echo $row['color']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['length']; 
            echo " (mm)";?></td>
            <td id="value10" style="font-weight: bold"><?php echo $row['value'];?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row['place'];?></td>    
        </tr>


                <?php
                    }    
                }

                ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any  ideas?

Comment: I don't think this need jQuery or javascript, you can have this in CSS and PHP, just check the value in php, add attribute class for both cases based on the value.

Comment: Good catch @mamounothman  For some reason I just assumed that these were form inputs

Comment: `td` element have not property `val` use `$("#value10").text();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't need jQuery, you can do it with PHP:

```php
<td id="value10" style="font-weight: bold; background: <?= ($row['value'] >= 10 ? 'green' : 'red'); ?>"><?= $row['value'];?></td>
```

There we are using a PHP's [short-hand ternary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).

Also I changed `<?php echo` to the short-hand `<?=` (it does exactly the same). For this last thing, you may want to check if your server supports it (available since version 5.4+).

Comment: it worked thanks ! What if i have 3parameters? Like: if $row['value'] = 0 then red , else if $row['value'] >0& $row['value'] <10 then οrange else green.

Comment: My main suggestion is that you _don't_ create such a "spaghetti code", and do all those value checks before (_e.g._ in the upper section of your script, or using any kind of application design pattern like _MVC_) instead of doing it inside the HTML. You'll eventually learn those things, but you may want to read further about that - the sooner the better.